Ubuntu 24.04.1 XAMPP MySQL Database not starting?
I was trying to open the MySQL Database from the XAMPP (8.2.12) that I just installed on fresh Ubuntu 24.04.1 system. While the Apache Web Server and ProFTPD is running, MySQL refuses to start:
XAMPP Panel Error Status
Here's the complete error log:
2024-09-29 22:01:48 401639 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/lampp/var/mysql
2024-09-29 22:01:48 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.32-MariaDB source revision c4143f909528e3fab0677a28631d10389354c491 as proces2024-09-29 22:01:48 0 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'key_buffer' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'key_buffer_size' instead.
s 401794
2024-09-29 22:01:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2024-09-29 22:01:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2024-09-29 22:01:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2024-09-29 22:01:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2024-09-29 22:01:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2024-09-29 22:01:48 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/tmp/user/0/ib6ZuSDa' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
2024-09-29 22:01:48 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
2024-09-29 22:01:48 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/tmp/user/0/ibXs4LuJ' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
2024-09-29 22:01:48 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
2024-09-29 22:01:48 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2024-09-29 22:01:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2024-09-29 22:01:48 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2024-09-29 22:01:48 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-09-29 22:01:48 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2024-09-29 22:01:48 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2024-09-29 22:01:48 401639 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/lampp/var/mysql/immanuel.pid ended
2024-09-29 22:06:09 405682 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/lampp/var/mysql
2024-09-29 22:06:09 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.32-MariaDB source revision c4143f909528e3fab0677a28631d10389354c491 as process 405833
2024-09-29 22:06:09 0 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'key_buffer' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'key_buffer_size' instead.
2024-09-29 22:06:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2024-09-29 22:06:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2024-09-29 22:06:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2024-09-29 22:06:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2024-09-29 22:06:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2024-09-29 22:06:09 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/tmp/user/0/ibyJHfgh' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
2024-09-29 22:06:09 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
2024-09-29 22:06:09 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/tmp/user/0/ibXryd3L' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
2024-09-29 22:06:09 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
2024-09-29 22:06:09 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2024-09-29 22:06:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2024-09-29 22:06:10 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2024-09-29 22:06:10 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-09-29 22:06:10 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2024-09-29 22:06:10 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2024-09-29 22:06:10 405682 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/lampp/var/mysql/immanuel.pid ended

I've tried numerous proposed solutions like this one, but none of them appears to be working.

I think the relevant error is the following:
[ERROR] mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/tmp/user/0/ib6ZuSDa' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")

From a search found Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_xxxx.MYI' (Errcode: 13) which says the permissions on /tmp are likely wrong.
Roy said:

They really should be read/write/execute for everyone with the sticky bit set.
chmod 1777 /tmp

Suggest trying the above.

The sticky bit add some restrictions to how other users interact with files not created or owned by them, so there's no reason to worry.


The trick was "chmod 1777 /tmp/user/0/", not the /tmp itself. After I've done that, MySQL is working perfectly fine. Thanks.

You should have done
chmod -R to recursively fix the permissions.
But the permissions needs to be not only on file but you should have the permissions properly on the tmp directory.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
